# Mysql UPDATE: nullable column gives error although there is a value

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-8.0

SQL weirdness! I am using a mysql 8 db and send an update statement to a table

```sql
UPDATE katalog
       SET katalog_status_id      = '1',
           lieferantennr          = '510181',
           artikelnummer          = '12345678',
           artikelbeschreibung    = 'dgdfgdfgdfg',
           artikelbeschreibung_en = '',
           kommentar              = 'test test ',
           kategorie_a            = '910',
           kategorie_b            = '270',
           datum_aenderung        = '2023-06-15 14:30:42'
       WHERE catalog_id = '21302'
```

Two problems:
I get the error message:

```
[2023-06-15 14:32:10] [23000][1048] Column 'datum_aenderung' cannot be null
```

and even weirder the column datum_aenderung  **can** be null and I already have datasets containing null for this column.

First I thought I have some framework weirdness here so I tried the sql statement directly in the console (using PhpStrom as IDE), but I still get this error message.

What am I overlooking?

Comment: Is there any triggers for katalog table? I don't know if it's related to your problem but have a look

Comment: @ErfanSaberi yes there are! Thank you for your input. I will check them out.

Comment: @ErfanSaberi That was the problem. The trigger inserted in a table, where the column was still limited. 
Now I know why I don't user triggers.  Do you want to post your suggestion as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because of a trigger that is controlling the update operation of the katalog table. Try disabling that trigger if it exists.
Notice that you should check why that trigger is there, it might be necessary to have it on that table, and there might be a reason that the framework added that trigger.